# CPU usage and memory of Gstreamer pipleline

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, x264

I'm using gstreamer to capture video from a webcam, encode it with x264 and stream it using a gstrtpbin. It works great. However, it uses about 50% of all four of my cores and a lot of memory. Is there anything I can do to lower the CPU and memory usage? Here's the pipeline.

```
pipeline_description = "gstrtpbin latency=0 max-latency=100 drop-on-latency=true use-pipeline-clock=true ntp-sync=true name=rtpbin " \
        "autovideosrc ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! " \
        "tee name=t_vid ! queue ! fpsdisplaysink name=fpssink text-overlay=false video-sink=xvimagesink signal-fps-measurements=true t_vid. ! " \
        "queue ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! x264enc pass=qual tune=zerolatency quantizer=40 ! queue ! rtph264pay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 " \
        "rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=%d host=%s sync=false async=false rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! " \
        "udpsink port=%d host=%s sync=false async=false name=vrtcpsink udpsrc port=%d ! " \
        "rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0 autoaudiosrc ! queue ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 " \
        "rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! udpsink port=%d host=%s sync=false async=false rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! " \
        "udpsink port=%d host=%s sync=false async=false udpsrc port=%d ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_1" % (VRTP_SEND_PORT, DEST,
        VRTCP_SEND_PORT, DEST, VRTCP_RECV_PORT, ARTP_SEND_PORT, DEST, ARTCP_SEND_PORT, DEST, ARTCP_RECV_PORT)
```

Comment: 30 frames per second at VGA resolution encoded into h.264 is /a lot/ of computation!

Comment: @joeforker: this is really a nice answer for performence, because i realized it, and i saw the differences with HDMI rendering goes very fast.

Comment: The queues all use memory. You might be able to move them around or limit their size.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue as well - using sync=false seems to trigger 100% CPU.  There is another thread [Streaming RTP/RTSP: sync/timestamp problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397655/streaming-rtp-rtsp-sync-timestamp-problems) that talks about this.  HTH

Answer (score 0):

I would run oprofile/sysprof to see which code the biggest offender is. You might be able to save a little by using less of the abstract sinks and sources (e.g. use xvimagesink directly instead of fpsdisplaysink). If you can, avoid ffmpegcolorspace (colorspace conversion in principle, the element won't do anything if not needed and only cause little overhead).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the frame-rate computation and more so it's overlay, you could shave off some CPU consumption that way, but as pointed out by joeforker, h264 is computationally quite intensive, so inspite of all the optimization in your pipeline, I doubt you'd see an improvement of more than 10-15%, unless one of the elements is buggy. Which is where ensonic's comment on profiling would be quite useful, especially if you are open to rewriting some of the elements i.e. replacing the ones shipped, with your own.