# Timestamping error/or comptuer too slow with gstreamer/gstbasesink in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, deployment, gstreamer

I am building a simple video player in Qt using gstreamer-1.0. When I run it from Qt, or .exe in my pc, everything runs and works ok. But when I try it from another pc, it plays for some seconds that it skips some seconds/minutes and so on. I guess the problem is with sync, I have tried setting d3dvidesink property: sync=false, but is the same. I have read many similiar threads but none seems to help.

**A lot of buffers are being dropped.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2846): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): 
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.**

I have tried setting different properties, but none helped. I have seen the following threads, but still the same problem:

[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11397655/streaming-rtp-rtsp-sync-timestamp-problems)
[Thread 2](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/There-may-be-a-timestamping-problem-or-this-computer-is-too-slow-td3807357.html)
[Thread 3](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Video-stream-timestamps-problem-td4657379.html)

On Thread 3 there is a suggestion setting "do-timestamp" property on appsrc to TRUE, but I use uridecodebin as source that has not a "do-timestamp" property.

My pipeline is as follows:

**uridecodebin ! audioconvert ! volume ! autoaudiosink ! videoconvert ! gamma ! d3dvideosink**

Thanks in Advance!

Here is some code from the elements creation/linking. Please comment if you need any other code.

```
    // Create the elements
   data.source        = gst_element_factory_make ( "uridecodebin",  "source" );
   data.audio_convert = gst_element_factory_make ( "audioconvert",  "audio_convert" );
   data.volume        = gst_element_factory_make ( "volume",        "volume");
   data.audio_sink    = gst_element_factory_make ( "autoaudiosink", "audio_sink" );
   data.video_convert = gst_element_factory_make ( "videoconvert",  "video_convert" ); 
   data.filter        = gst_element_factory_make ( "gamma",         "filter"); 
   data.video_sink    = gst_element_factory_make ( "d3dvideosink",  "video_sink" );


   // Create the empty pipeline
   data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
   if (!data.pipeline || !data.source || !data.audio_convert || !data.volume || !data.audio_sink
                      || !data.video_convert || !data.filter  || !data.video_sink ) {
   g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");}
   return ;
   }

   // Build the pipeline. Note that we are NOT linking the source at this point. We will do it later.
   gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source, data.audio_convert , data.volume, data.audio_sink,
                                                   data.video_convert, data.filter, data.video_sink, NULL);


if (!gst_element_link (data.audio_convert, data.volume)) {
g_printerr ("Elements AUDIO_CONVERT - VOLUME could not be linked.\n");
gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
return ;
}

if (!gst_element_link (data.volume, data.audio_sink)) {
g_printerr ("Elements VOLUME - AUDIO_SINK could not be linked.\n");
gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
return ;
}

if (!gst_element_link(data.video_convert, data.filter)) {
g_printerr("Elements VIDEO_CONVERT - FILTER could not be linked.\n");
gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
return ;
}

if (!gst_element_link(data.filter, data.video_sink)) {
g_printerr("Elements FILTER - VIDEO_SINK could not be linked.\n");
gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
return ;
}
```

When I open video:

```
 // Set the URI to play
    QString filePath = "file:///"+filename;
    QByteArray ba = filePath.toLatin1();
    const char *c_filePath = ba.data();

ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

gint64 max_lateness = 2000000; //2 milli sec
g_object_set (data.source, "uri", c_filePath, NULL);

// I have tried setting the following properties, but none helped
// g_object_set (data.source, "do-timestamp", true, NULL);
// g_object_set( data.video_sink, "sync", false, NULL);
// g_object_set( data.video_sink, "max-lateness", max_lateness, NULL);
qDebug() << &c_filePath;

// Link video_sink with playingWidget->winId()
gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle (GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (data.video_sink), xwinid);


// Connect to the pad-added signal
   g_signal_connect (data.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data) ;

// Start playing
ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
       gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
       gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
         // Exit application
         QTimer::singleShot(0, QApplication::activeWindow(), SLOT(quit()));}

data.playing = TRUE;
data.rate    = 1.0;

// Iterate - gets the position and length every 200 msec
g_print ("Running...\n");
emit setMsg( "Running...\n" );
currFileName = filename;
timer->start(500);
```

Pad_added_handler:

```
void gst_pipeline::pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data)
{
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;

     GstPad *sink_pad_audio = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->audio_queue, "sink");
     GstPad *sink_pad_video = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->video_queue, "sink");


  g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));

    // If our audio converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here
    if (gst_pad_is_linked (sink_pad_audio))
    {
         g_print (" We have already linked sink_pad_audio. Ignoring.\n"); 
         // goto exit;
    }

    // If our video converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here
    if (gst_pad_is_linked (sink_pad_video))
    {
         g_print (" We have already linked sink_pad_video. Ignoring.\n");
         // goto exit;
    }

    // Check the new pad's type
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad); //gst_pad_get_caps
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);


   if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "audio/x-raw"))
  {
    // Attempt the link
    ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_audio);


     if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
       {  g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type); }
     else
       {  g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);   }
  }
   else if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "video/x-raw"))
  {
    // Attempt the link
    ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_video);

     if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret))
       {  g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);   }
     else
       {  g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);     }
  }
      else
    {
      g_print (" It has type '%s' which is not audio/x-raw OR video/x-raw. Ignoring.\n", new_pad_type);
      goto exit;
    }

   exit:
    // Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them
    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
    { gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps); g_print("EXIT"); msg_STRING2 += "EXIT\n" ;     }

    // Unreference the sink pad
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad_audio);
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad_video);

}
```

Comment: You need to include your actual code, so that people can get some idea what is actually going on.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ChrisBeck , I edited the question and added some code. Please comment if you need more code.

Comment: Can you give us some general specs on the machines you're testing on, and the size of videos you're working with.  I see a few things that could be improved depending on the hardware you're on.

Comment: I have a Fujitsu i5 2.4GHz, ram4; also tried in a dell i3, ram4, the same. I try with different videos, the same. I asked here [here](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Timestamping-error-or-comptuer-too-slow-with-gstreamer-gstbasesink-in-Qt-td4673555.html) and tried the suggestion, adding the queue element, but is still the same. If you need any details about my graphic card, [here](http://i58.tinypic.com/fw2hw6.jpg) is a screenshot.

Comment: [here](http://i772.photobucket.com/albums/yy7/Dionis_Prifti/graphicCard_zpsjm5d8ofr.png) is the screenshot, sorry

Comment: any suggestion @mpr ?

Comment: On these two computers, can they both handle the simpler command line pipeline: `gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file://...`?  If so, that would rule out hardware issues and we'd need to see more of your code, probably in pad_added_handler.

Comment: @mpr on my computer when I try with gst-launch/run from qt/from .exe everything works fine. This problem is only on other computers. Thats why I guess it might be a deploying problem, maybe some .dll/linking needed. I have edit the question and edded the code of pad_added_handler.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to maybe try a much simpler pipeline, say with a `videotestsrc`, and verify that it works on the other system.  It's hard to tell at what level the issue is: hardware, OS configuration, GStreamer, or pipeline.  You can also try using GST_DEBUG_DUMP_DOT_DIR env var to collect some pipeline analysis on the non-functioning machine.

Comment: I have this problem, did you ever find a solution? I have a 9 second delay between "pressing play" and the sink displaying it. With those same timing errors.

Comment: @Dave I just noticed the comment here, just not to leave it unanswered: I don't remember anymore, to be honest, but I guess you would have already found a solution during this long time. What I remember is that GStreamer pipelines can get too complicated to understand if you are new to the library, so a very good startegy that helped me a lot: keep the pipeline as simple as possible and then add build slowly your logic there.